# ASP.NET Identity table update/migration at runtime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-identity

We are creating a new web app that will update/migrate an existing DB, including the user information. Since the passwords are SHA encrypted in the user table, I would need to migrate during runtime, as the users log in.

In order to do this, I want to hook into the user validation code - if the user exists in the new Identity user table, good - we're done - use it. Else check the old user table (and validate the password with the old password validation mechanism), create a user in the new Identity table, delete the old user from the old table (or flag as migrated), then return that new Identity user.

Is this a reasonable approach? Are there any examples of this I could use as a starting point?

Note: I would like to use the standard ASP.NET Identity 2.0 table structure with the exception that user ids will be int - since the existing schema relies on an int user id.

**Edit**: The existing web app will go away and we will replace it with the new web app (with ASP.NET Identity) but we will still point to the existing DB (containing the old user table and other data). The addition to the DB will be the new ASP.NET Identity tables and any updates to join to those tables instead of the old user table.

Comment: why does the SHA encrypted passwords require you to migrate at runtime?  You can store the SHA in the new db.

Comment: I believe SHA is one-way, right? So I can't decrypt the password and do a migration if the encryption scheme isn't the same. The hash I have in the old table is not the same hash in the new table.

Comment: ok don't put it in the new table put it in a special table called "old_password_sha_hashes" and validate one time against that table if you need to.  If you migrate to a new database you don't want to make your application connect to the old one and you don't want to maintain the old one after you migrate.

Comment: @Hogan not sure how that is significantly different from using the old user table and validate one time against the hash in that old table - as I mentioned in my question, unless my question wasn't clear.

Comment: It is significantly different -- your question implies leaving the old server up and available after the migration.  This means you have not migrated -- if you are still accessing data on the old server it is active and in production.  Whatever the reason for the migration, you want to do the migration and then de-comission the old server.  With your design you  have to maintain that server until every user has logged on once.  In other words; that server will never go away.

Comment: @Hogan I've clarified the question. Thanks for pointing out the confusion.

Comment: OH! This is just a migration of the user tables.  Sorry :(

Comment: I think the first line should be ".. to update an existing DBs User information."  Don't use the scary migration word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A a good way to deal with legacy password hashes described in the official migration guide: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity

On that page search for `SQLPasswordHasher` and see how they do the password matching.

Basically the idea is simple - when you update your system to Identity you copy all the old users and their hashes (and salts) into new Identity table. Then you tell identity to use the above-mentioned `SQLPasswordHasher` to try to match either the old SHA hash or (for already updated users) the new-style hash. And (optionally) you can update the hash for freshly logged in users to the new-style.

I have done this with a few projects and there was not a single problem.

Comment: How do you tell Identity which columns hold the legacy passwordhash and legacy salt?

Comment: In `PasswordValidator` - if you look through the linked code it'll be clear. You keep legacy password and hash in the same column as the non-legacy passwords. And `PasswordValidator` knows how to compare old hashes.

Comment: My legacy password and salt are currently in 2 separate columns. Looks like I should combine them, delimited by "|" (pipe), into the PasswordHash column. And returning SuccessRehashNeeded will generate the Identity hash and update column. Is all that accurate?

Comment: @Ed.S. Something like that. The article uses separator `|` (pipe) between hash, type of hash and salt. If you have only one type of hash in your legacy app, you can amend the provided code and exclude the hash type, only have `<hash>|<salt>`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good place would be in `ApplicationOAuthProvider:GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`, where we are doing a `userManager.FindAsync()` to look for user (with pw) in new User table. If that fails (user == null check), I'll add the code to look for user in old User table and if there (and password passes hash test), will create user in new User table with old User table data and new password hash - and then mark old User table record as "migrated" or "upgraded"